Flynas connecting flight JED-DEL via Riyadh airport
I booked a flight ticket from Jeddah to Delhi, which has one stop at Riyadh airport. The e-ticket has one PNR and the itinerary is as follows:
. 1st flight scheduled from Jeddah T1 to Riyadh T5
. 2nd flight scheduled from Riyadh- 3 to Delhi T3.
The transit time between the 2 flights is 2 hours and 20 minutes.
Now I need advice on the following, which the airlines couldn't answer.

The traveler is 63 years old with no capability to walk fast, and can't speak English or Arabic.

In the given scenario, will the passenger need to do the immigration only once at Jeddah airport or again will he have to do the process all over at the Riyadh airport?
What facilities are available at the Riyadh airport for terminal change between Terminal 5 and Terminal 3, and how much time does it take?
Will a person who is traveling for the first time in Saudi with limited capacity to walk, be able to catch the second flight with in 2 hours?

Did you look into asking assistance at any of the airports? At 63 and healthy that might not be needed but if walking fast is hard or not speaking the language scary it might help having a good journey. If they speak a language the flight crew members speak those can help with communicating with the helpers.

I have tried contacting the airport authorities but unfortunately could not get success.

What languages to they speak/read? Are they used to airports?

Hindi (India), He is older so forgets easily and is not aware of airports process.

Jeddah and Riyadh are both in Saudi Arabia, so there will not be any immigration processing in Jeddah, but only in Riyadh (the Jeddah-Riyadh is an internal flight).
In Jeddah, they will have to get though check-in, security, get to the gate, and onto the plane.
In Riyadh, Terminal 5 is completely separate from Terminals 1 to 4, which means they will probably have to:

deplane
Take a shuttle bus to Terminal 3
Go through exit passport control
Go through security
Get to the gate
Board

The order may vary (I’m not familiar with the layout and procedures at KKIA), but it’s likely they will have to do all that.
It’s probably a good idea to use the assistance services of the airport (see https://www.kkia.sa/en/Services/Pages/SpecialNeeds.aspx for contact info) or of the airline (see https://www.flynas.com/en/plan-my-trip/special-services which is not very informative, it basically says you need to contact their call centre).
Other than the language barrier (which depends a lot on what languages they speak/read, and how used they are of air travel), I wouldn’t expect the connection to be a problem in the given time. It’s a bit more complex than most connections, but 2 hours 20 should be plenty of time.

Thank you so much, your answer provides a relief.
